# Getting error message for Maven on selenium , IntelliJ

Tags: java

Getting Error message for Maven in Intellij for selenium.

java: illegal start of expression

Hi,
I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.8617.56, built on January 26, 2023. Later on installed selenium and the created , chrome driver, then created package but was unable to see Maven on left side panel so selected Java as language build as Maven and added advance setting and created project. Added dependency also in pom file. Created class and the moment I type webdriver driver =new webdriver(); java utility get activated and I get below override methods. And I am getting error message when I run it .

I am not sure why java utility gets invoked.

```
timport org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class FirstMavenPgm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new WebDriver() {
            @Override
            public void get(String url) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public String getCurrentUrl() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getTitle() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public WebElement findElement(By by) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getPageSource() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {

            }

            @Override
            public void quit() {

            }

            @Override
            public Set<String> getWindowHandles() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getWindowHandle() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public TargetLocator switchTo() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Navigation navigate() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Options manage() {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method definitions were generated because you did a new WebDriver(). WebDriver Is an interface (not a concrete class) with these methods so they need to be defined somewhere. Did you perhaps mean to create an instance of one of these ChromeDriver, ChromiumDriver, EdgeDriver, EventFiringWebDriver, FirefoxDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, RemoteWebDriver, SafariDriver?

Comment: Thanks William for your reply. Actually I am new to selenium  and wanted to open one Browser by writing this program. I just want to open browser and then close it using Maven

Comment: Thanks William, understood now I have to write  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  however I was writing it as WebDriver which is incorrect. Thanks for your help